# How to concisely express"min of the intersections of two functions"?

Tags: notation

I have two functions: $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

I wonder if there is a way to mathematically express "the min of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ intersections"?

$\min(f(x)=g(x))$ is what I could think of, but it doesn't seems right.

Comment: David Lui's answer below is the way to go if you want the least $x$ such that $f(x) = g(x)$, and your domain is $\mathbb{R}$. If you instead want the least value of $f(x)$ such that $f(x) = g(x)$ then (for $X$ the intersection of the domains of $f$ and $g$) use $\min{(\{\,f(x) \,\mid\, f(x) = g(x)\,, \, x \in X \,\})}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use set-builder notation. You want to find the minimum of the set of intersections.

$min(\{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) = g(x) \})$